# Task Sequence fails with Task Sequence error 0x00000001 at the step "error in the task sequence."

Tags: sccm, mdt

I'm attempting to deploy Windows Server 2019 to a virtual machine and I keep getting this error message: 
[image: error message]

I suspect that the error is not actually at this stage, but I can't seem to track it down, and the SMSTS log is out of date.

Edit: Got the log, it looks like it's failing on trying to install the role outside of the OS, but in the task sequence, installing the role is in the post install group?

```
   This script should only run in the full OS.  ZTIOSRole   9/27/2019 1:01:29 PM    0 (0x0000)
    ZTI ERROR - Non-zero return code by ZTIOSRole, rc = 1   ZTIOSRole   9/27/2019 1:01:29 PM    0 (0x0000)
    Microsoft Deployment Toolkit version: 6.3.8450.1000 ztimovestatestore   9/27/2019 1:01:33 PM    0 (0x0000)
    The task sequencer log is located at X:\WINDOWS\TEMP\SMSTSLog\SMSTS.LOG.  For task sequence failures, please consult this log.  ztimovestatestore   9/27/2019 1:01:33 PM    0 (0x0000)
    ztimovestatestore processing completed successfully.    ztimovestatestore   9/27/2019 1:01:33 PM    0 (0x0000)
    Microsoft Deployment Toolkit version: 6.3.8450.1000 zticopylogs 9/27/2019 1:01:35 PM    0 (0x0000)
    The task sequencer log is located at X:\WINDOWS\TEMP\SMSTSLog\SMSTS.LOG.  For task sequence failures, please consult this log.  zticopylogs 9/27/2019 1:01:35 PM    0 (0x0000)
    Unable to copy log to the network as no SLShare value was specified.    zticopylogs 9/27/2019 1:01:35 PM    0 (0x0000)
    No system restore needed, WMI object not present.   zticopylogs 9/27/2019 1:01:35 PM    0 (0x0000)
    Cleaning up default wallpaper registry keys zticopylogs 9/27/2019 1:01:35 PM    0 (0x0000)
    zticopylogs processing completed successfully.  zticopylogs 9/27/2019 1:01:35 PM    0 (0x0000)
```

The task sequence itself:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You should monitor the build process then you`ll know at what stage it is failing. Thanks.

Comment: It goes by too fast to really get an idea where.

Comment: Make the error action to just hang/display the summary page instead of restart. We need those logs.

Comment: @ElliotLabsLLC Good idea, I'll try that out.

Comment: I have added the logs.

Comment: Based upon the error, it looks as though the role is trying to be installed while the deployment is in the Windows PE phase. According to the error log, it should only have role deployment after the OS has been installed and booted from. The OS Role step is going to operate on the live (`dism -online`) system.   
If that fixes it, please shoot me a heads up and i'll write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a reboot after installing your OS, Add a reboot computer step so that it boots from disk and you should be good to go.

When you do go to reboot the computer, ensure that the MDT files are copied to disk so that the system doesn't just boot into the local admin account and not start MDT.

[image: No reboot found in task sequence]